# Sorting and merge values of a python dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I got a problem with a dict I want to sort in python 3.5.
It looks like :

```
d = {'automate': <Routing.Route.Route object at 0x2b7f84835c18>, 
    'index': <.Routing.Route.Route object at 0x2b7f8486e5c0>,
    'index_1': <Routing.Route.Route object at 0x2b7f8483d400>,
    'index_2': <Routing.Route.Route object at 0x2b7f84835f98>,
    'second': <Routing.Route.Route object at 0x2b7f8483d470>,
    'test_route_parameters': <Routing.Route.Route object at 0x2b7f8486e588>}
```

Where Route class has name, package_name attributes.

I want to print this dict like:

```
>> Package_name1:
     automate
     index
     index_1

   Package_name2:
     second
     index_2

   Package_name3:
     test_route_parameters
```

How can I sort my dict by package_name and print it to match the above output?

Have a good day and thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Ofc, I'll update my question. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
{v.package_name:[k for k in d if d[k].package_name==v.package_name] for v in d.values()}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was I expected. I take note for the next time

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Loop through the dictionary and check if the package name in value is present in the sorted_dict. If not, add a list as value and package_name as key and then just append the keys to each package_name. Runs in O(n).

```
sorted_dict = {}
for key in d:
    if d[key] not in sorted_dict:
        sorted_dict[d[key].package_name] = []
sorted_dict[d[key].package_name].append(d[key])
```